# awk multiplication of all rows in a table with first row of the table

Tags: awk

I have a table with several columns and I want to multiply all rows in the table with the values of the first row (column by column).

Table:

```
0,140   0,130   0,140   0,150   0,160 <- values to be used for multiplication
1,270   1,190   6,080   3,760   2,810
1,290   1,140   6,110   3,900   3,050
1,370   1,160   6,310   4,030   3,020
1,370   1,150   6,500   3,970   3,070
```

Result:

```
0,178   0,155   0,851   0,564   0,450
0,181   0,148   0,855   0,585   0,488
0,192   0,151   0,883   0,605   0,483
0,192   0,150   0,910   0,596   0,491
```

I have some experience with `awk` but I couldn't figure out the solution.

Comment: Could you share your attempts made with your _experience_ in `Awk`?

Comment: Also, if this is homework, you should be honest and tell us.

Comment: This is no homework, it is part of my scientific work. The aim is to calculate the concentartion of samples from a set of measurements. I was actuallly dealing with two tables, one with the measured data with up to 30 columns and 1000 rows and the list with the constants. But I could not figure out how to muliply the table with one row with the rows of the other table. I came closer by just pasting the single line on top of the big table but did not manage to get multiplication over the whole table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'NR==1{split($0,m);CONVFMT="%.3f";next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i*m[i]} 1' file
0.178 0.155 0.851 0.564 0.450
0.181 0.148 0.855 0.585 0.488
0.192 0.151 0.883 0.605 0.483
0.192 0.149 0.910 0.596 0.491
```

I used `.`s instead of `,`s in my sample as that's what my locale uses for decimal point.

Comment: Nice Ed, didn't know that link :) will post that link too(for new users I think)